# Pass object function as callback

Tags: php, callback

are there ways to pass a "method reference" to a function that accept a callback?

Eg.:

```
function ex($callback){
   $callback();
}

$obj = (object) ['f' => function(){echo "hello";}];
ex($obj->a)
```

Obviously this is a very simplistic case, image having a complex object `$obj` with parameters inside

Comment: Unless the method is static, you need to provide an object to call it on.

Comment: If you use the same property name, then yes, `f` is not `a` https://3v4l.org/XgQG6 or I just don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not work like Javascript.

This code:

```php
$obj = (object) ['f' => function(){echo "hello";}];
```

Does not define "an object with method `f()`" it defines "an object with property `f` that *happens* to be a callable type".

Calling `$obj->f();` directly results in:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::f()

It would need to be specially handled like:

```php
$func = $obj->f;
$func();
```

Or:

```php
($obj->f)();
```

While not a wholly accurate statement, you could consider it that callable types need the equivalent of "being dereferenced" before they can actually be called.

You example is something of a "successful error" in that it attempts to use "first class functions" which PHP does not have, but on a malformed object that allows this to not fail.

Using a proper class:

```php
function ex($callback){
   $callback();
}

class Example {
  public function f_instance() {
    echo "instance call\n";
  }
  
  public static function f_static() {
    echo "static call\n";
  }
}

ex(['Example', 'f_static']);

$e = new Example();
ex([$e, 'f_instance']);
```

Output:

```
static call
instance call
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php